# Get the last key of a Map object

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to get the last key present in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

```js
var myMap = new Map()
myMap.set('0', 'foo')
myMap.set('1', 'bar')
myMap.set('2', 'baz')

myMap.getLastKey() // 2
```

Currently I need a loop to get this value but it looks over-complicated:

```js
var myMap = new Map()
myMap.set('0', 'foo')
myMap.set('1', 'bar')
myMap.set('2', 'baz')

let iterator = myMap.keys();

let mapLastValue

for (i = 0; i < myMap.size; i += 1) {
  mapLastValue = iterator.next().value
}

console.log(mapLastValue) // 2
```

Comment: Maybe `[...myMap.keys()].pop()`, not as clean as a single method, but easier than writing a loop imo

Comment: Yeah awesome that's better enough. Can you write it as the answer?

Comment: No worries. Seems like Adam has given an answer using the same solution, so feel free to accept that ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of keys, convert it to an array, and then get the last key. Use that:

```js
var myMap = new Map()
myMap.set('0', 'foo')
myMap.set('1', 'bar')
myMap.set('2', 'baz')


let lastKey = [...myMap.keys()].pop(); // gets the last key

console.log(myMap.get(lastKey)) // baz
```

Comment: Works like a charm thanks +1 Just be aware that `console.log(myMap.get(lastKey))` don't show `2` but `baz`

Comment: Do you need the value or the key?

Comment: Never wrote the term `value` ;)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Fixed it

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
 let myMap= {
      0: 'foo',
      1: 'bar',
      2: 'baz'
    }
    
    let lastKey = Object.keys(myMap).pop()
    let lastValue = myMap[Object.keys(myMap).pop()]
```

Comment: OP is looking for an answer which is using a Map, not an object. Also, the order of Object.keys is not guaranteed in the older spec, so browsers/environments that aren't using the newest spec won't necessarily produce an array of keys in the order of `["0", "1", "2"]`